# Copy and Paste the Last Single Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following codes work: Searching for data in the "A2: A10" range on the "produce" page on the "A" page. He copies all the lines he finds to the "B" page. If there is data on two different lines with the same name in "A" page, it copies to the "B" page on both lines. What I want to do is:
If there is 2 lines from the data it searches on the "A" page, I would like to copy the one on the bottom line and paste it to the "B" page. For example:

```
A Column B Column
1          A1
2          A2
3          A3
4          A2
```

Here, there is data named "A2" in both line 2 and line 4. Copy line 4 and paste it on "B" page.

I present my thanks for your support in advance.

Sheet Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Vj2HvEhuOI5uxFFj9x57jN9MWPoTkb9euSrpDnkGXk/edit?usp=sharing

Script;:

```
function yenidenuret(searchCol) 
{
  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  
  var rr = s.getActiveRange();
  var satircek = rr.getRow();   
  //  var urunadicek = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('abc').getRange('B2:B14').getValues();  
  
  // var result = [].concat.apply([], urunadicek).filter(String); 
  

   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  
  var uretilecekveriler=ss.getSheetByName('produce').getRange('A2:A10').getValues();//default
  var findArray = [].concat.apply([], uretilecekveriler).filter(String);
  var searchCol=searchCol||"producenow";//default

  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('A');
  var shh=ss.getSheetByName('B');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var cObj={};
    

  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) 
  {
    cObj[String(hA[i]).toLowerCase()]=i+1;
       
  }
  var srg=sh.getRange(1,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  for(var i=0;i<findArray.length;i++) {
   
    
    var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll();
       
    var d=0;

    if(f.length>0) {
      for(var j=0;j<f.length;j++) {
        
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(' Üretime hazır olan kitaplar aktarılıyor.... İŞLEM TAMAMLANDI KUTUSU ÇIKANA KADAR BEKLEYİNİZ!!!!!', 'Transfer İşlemi', /*timeoutSeconds*/ 6);
        
      
        ss.getSheetByName('B').insertRowsBefore(ss.getRange('2:2').getRow(), 1);
        ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, ss.getRange('2:2').getNumColumns());
        var target = ss.getSheetByName('B').getRange(2, 1);
        sh.getRange(f[j].getRow()-d, 1, 1,ss.getSheetByName('A').getLastColumn()).copyTo(target);
        
        
         
   
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
        
        
        
        //sh.deleteRow(f[j].getRow()-d++);    

        
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: By the way, when I saw your this script, it seems that you merge the both scripts of pattern 1 and pattern 2. How about this? And also, in my environment, unfortunately, no error occurs even when your current script is used. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, if you changed the Spreadsheet, an error might occur. Because my proposal is for your initial Spreadsheet in your question. Please be careful this.

Comment: From `Thank you. Command is running. But he finds it adding twice.`, this means that the script works. But in your script, both pattern 1 and pattern 2 are used. The reason of `But he finds it adding twice.` is this. Please use one of 2 patterns and run again.

Comment: I added whole script including the pattern1 or pattern2 in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search the column of "producenow" in the sheet "A" using the values retrieved from the cells "A2:A10" in the sheet "produce".
- When the multiple values are searched by one value, you want to retrieve only the bottom row.
- You want to put the retrieved rows to the last row of the sheet "B".

In order to achieve above, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modified script:

- All values retrieved from `var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll()` are used. In this case, I think that the last row can be used for your goal.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- `copyTo` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will be high.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified as follows. Please modify the for loop of `for(var i=0;i<findArray.length;i++) {}` as follows.

```
for(var i=0;i<findArray.length;i++) {
  var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll();
  var d=0;
  if(f.length>0) {
    f = f.pop();  // Added
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(' Üretime hazır olan kitaplar aktarılıyor.... İŞLEM TAMAMLANDI KUTUSU ÇIKANA KADAR BEKLEYİNİZ!!!!!', 'Transfer İşlemi', /*timeoutSeconds*/ 6);
    ss.getSheetByName('B').insertRowsBefore(ss.getRange('2:2').getRow(), 1);
    ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, ss.getRange('2:2').getNumColumns());
    var target = ss.getSheetByName('B').getRange(2, 1);
    sh.getRange(f.getRow()-d, 1, 1,ss.getSheetByName('A').getLastColumn()).copyTo(target);  // Modified
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified for reducing the process cost as follows. At first, the values are created, and then, the values are put to the Spreadsheet. In this case, please modify the below script of `var srg=sh.getRange(1,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow(), 1);` as follows.

```
var srg=sh.getRange(1,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow(), 1);

var values = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var res = findArray.reduce((ar, r) => {
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()] - 1] == r) {
      ar.push(values[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  return ar;
}, []).reverse();
if (res.length > 0) {
  var lastRow = shh.getLastRow();
  shh.getRange(lastRow == 0 ? 2 : lastRow + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

### Added:

Please use one of the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

```
function yenidenuret(searchCol)  {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rr = s.getActiveRange();
  var satircek = rr.getRow();   
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var uretilecekveriler=ss.getSheetByName('produce').getRange('A2:A10').getValues();//default
  var findArray = [].concat.apply([], uretilecekveriler).filter(String);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('A');
  var shh=ss.getSheetByName('B');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var cObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    cObj[String(hA[i]).toLowerCase()]=i+1;
  }
  var searchCol=searchCol||"producenow";//default
  var srg=sh.getRange(1,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  
  for(var i=0;i<findArray.length;i++) {
    var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll();
    var d=0;
    if(f.length>0) {
      f = f.pop();  // Added
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(' Üretime hazır olan kitaplar aktarılıyor.... İŞLEM TAMAMLANDI KUTUSU ÇIKANA KADAR BEKLEYİNİZ!!!!!', 'Transfer İşlemi', /*timeoutSeconds*/ 6);
      ss.getSheetByName('B').insertRowsBefore(ss.getRange('2:2').getRow(), 1);
      ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, ss.getRange('2:2').getNumColumns());
      var target = ss.getSheetByName('B').getRange(2, 1);
      sh.getRange(f.getRow()-d, 1, 1,ss.getSheetByName('A').getLastColumn()).copyTo(target);  // Modified
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

```
function yenidenuret(searchCol)  {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rr = s.getActiveRange();
  var satircek = rr.getRow();   
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var uretilecekveriler=ss.getSheetByName('produce').getRange('A2:A10').getValues();//default
  var findArray = [].concat.apply([], uretilecekveriler).filter(String);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('A');
  var shh=ss.getSheetByName('B');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var cObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    cObj[String(hA[i]).toLowerCase()]=i+1;
  }
  var searchCol=searchCol||"producenow";//default
  var srg=sh.getRange(1,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  
  var values = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var res = findArray.reduce((ar, r) => {
    for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (values[i][cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()] - 1] == r) {
        ar.push(values[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  if (res.length > 0) {
    var lastRow = shh.getLastRow();
    shh.getRange(lastRow == 0 ? 2 : lastRow + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will use "Pattern 1". Because I want to copy the cells with their formats.

Comment: @Halit Thank you for replying. It's no problem. So I proposed 2 patterns. By the way, can I ask you whether your issue was resolved?